# Unsupported protocol 'MPLSCP' (0x8281) received. Mikrotik + pptp linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, mikrotik, pptp

Настроил сервер pptp на mikrotik, windows10 клиент подключается, а ubuntu 16.04 нет.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/ppp/peers/workvpn
pty "pptp vpn-server --nolaunchpppd"
name ololo
remotename workvpn
require-mppe-128
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
ipparam workvpn
debug


root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/ppp/options.pptp
lock
noauth
refuse-pap
refuse-eap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
nobsdcomp
nodeflate

root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client        server  secret                  IP addresses
ololo workvpn mppere3234 *
```

лог

```
root@ubuntu:~# pon workvpn nodetach
using channel 41
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xca85ab51> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <auth chap MS-v2> <mru 1450> <magic 0x963ab216>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <auth chap MS-v2> <mru 1450> <magic 0x963ab216>]
rcvd [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <magic 0xca85ab51>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <magic 0xca85ab51>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xca85ab51]
rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x1 <3443c100f50972d6cae92cfb2cb9133a>, name = "MikroTik"]
added response cache entry 0
sent [CHAP Response id=0x1 <c6d8c8402f7e46bd055b63cf144ef5230000000000000000db94ad3c4491a66212d7906c437b05ae3441f6fafd8ebd8000>, name = "vadim"]
rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x963ab216]
rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x1 "S=A73B22BDE66F6F6C7ABBD245664ECF44155FE13E"]
response found in cache (entry 0)
CHAP authentication succeeded
sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 10.158.210.86>]
sent [IPCP TermAck id=0x1]
rcvd [proto=0x8281] 01 01 00 04
**Unsupported protocol 'MPLSCP' (0x8281) received**
sent [LCP ProtRej id=0x3 82 81 01 01 00 04]
rcvd [CCP ConfReq id=0x1]
sent [CCP ConfAck id=0x1]
rcvd [CCP ConfRej id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
MPPE required but peer refused
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x4 "MPPE required but peer refused"]
rcvd [LCP TermAck id=0x4]
Connection terminated.
```

Comment: Собственно вот: "MPPE required but peer refused". Линукс требует шифрования MPPE, а микротик отказывается его предоставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В микротике ppp - profiles скопируй профиль default-securyty. Удостоверься что в скопированном use encription - yes. Поставь этот профиль в соединение микротика.

Comment: Да, все верно, проблема была в use encription